# How to show AlertDialog before back to Activity?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to show a confirm AlertDialog before user press on back button or Activity going Pause.
I tried this code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    AlertDialog.Builder confirmBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(DoExam.this);
    confirmBuilder.setTitle("Confirm Exit");
    confirmBuilder.setMessage("are you sure to exit form this activity");
    confirmBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    confirmBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    AlertDialog confirmDialog=confirmBuilder.create();
    confirmDialog.show();
}
```

But it disappeared immediately at the same time the app back to previous activity.
I tried also to put the code at onPause method but I got the same problem.

Any help about show alert dialog and back to previous activity if clicked yes and keep user in the Activity if clicked no?

Comment: use super.onBackPressed() only if you want the default to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are calling `super.onBackPressed();` remove that and see what happens. the `super.onBackPressed();` is meant to trigger the default action of closing the activity. you need to defer that call when the user dismisses the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {


AlertDialog.Builder confirmBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(DoExam.this);
confirmBuilder.setTitle("Confirm Exit");
confirmBuilder.setMessage("are you sure to exit form this activity");
confirmBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // do any action you require on click
        DoExam.super.onBackPressed();
    }
});
confirmBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }
});
AlertDialog confirmDialog=confirmBuilder.create();
confirmDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Remove `super.onBackPressed();` and add it in `onClick(...)` of your posetive **Yes** button of your Alertdialog..

like this

```
confirmBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {         super.onBackPressed();
```

} });